# .htaccess url rewrite remove string

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls in the following format:

`http://localhost/profile.php?name=billgates`

I have used the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*?)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profile\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?profile\.php$ /profile/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Which converts urls to the format:

`http://localhost/profile/billgates`

Please let me know how I can edit the .htacces file to remove the profile/ and make urls in the format:

`http://localhost/billgates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be as restrictive as possible with the regex in order to avoid conflicts. For example, you need to be able to differentiate between `/<some-name>` and `/<some-page>` (if that is a thing on your site).

I'll assume that *names* can only consist of lowercase letters, as per your example.

You should also have the external redirect *before* the internal rewrite.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profile\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+?)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Since the regex is now more restrictive (only lowercase letters) the filesystem check that checks that the request does not match to a file can be removed (files in the document root are unlikely only going to consist of lowercase letters).